# Unable to install Mkahawa (14.10): dependency is not satisfiable - libccls

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, 14.10

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10. I'm attempting to install Mkahawa to see if it will meet my needs. Unfortunately, when I opened the .deb file with Ubuntu Software Centre, I was given this error message: "Dependency is not satisfiable: libccls". I've included a quick screenshot:

[image: Mkahawa screenshot]

What does this mean?

Comment: I have experimented with **Mkahawa** under 12.04 LTS, and possibly 14.04 LTS. However, I had to compile from source AND fix minor library/dependencies to achieve this. *How adventurous are you?*

Comment: Hit me with anything you've got. I'm just in the preliminary stages of planning an internet cafe, and I'm trying to experiment with Mkahawa on my dual boot laptop. If I kill this Ubuntu installation somehow, I'll live, I'll just reclaim that partition with Windows 7, and then reinstall 14.04. Why, is it going to be dangerous? I like adventure.

Comment: Which version did you try? SourceForge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mkahawa/) has v4.2 32bit.

Comment: You may simply need to also install the CCLS library. I need to check my old notes.

Comment: Right, it was from source forge. Here's the [link](http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) I noticed it was a i386 file. I should mention I'm running 64-bit 14.10.

Comment: Try downloading the missing library (.deb) from SourceForge. Follow link 'Browse All Files' (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mkahawa/files/).

Comment: Well, I successfully installed libccls, however when I went back and tried to install Mkahawa Server, I got the same error message: dependency is not satisfiable - libccls. Unless I need a reboot after installing libccls? I'll try that. Also note I installed the AMD 64 version of CCLS... maybe that's messing me up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18984/discussion-between-lucas-w-and-david6).

Comment: Sorry, I will do more research and post a more complete answer. *Time zone and work commitments prevent any further participation at this time.*

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libccls`